# How to make the int values of an Enum to match the corresponding database record id?

Tags: python, enums, peewee

I have a database table that contains specific companies that are accessed "statically" throughout the code and for which would be great to have a "static" way to refer to them, for example:

```
from enum import Enum, auto()

class CompanyEnum(Enum):
     APPLE = auto()
     AMAZON = auto()
     META = auto()
```

I would like the int value of the Enum to match the database id corresponding to those companies BUT of course I don't want the hardcoded `id` in the static Enum definition as that would be a terrible solution. Why would that be a terrible solution? because there is no guarantee that if the database is recreated from a backup or re-generated, the artificial ids will remain the same for those companies.

I can do something like (assuming that I am using Peewee):

```
from functools import lru_cache
from enum import Enum, auto()
from models import Company

class CompanyEnum(Enum):
     APPLE = auto()
     AMAZON = auto()
     META = auto()

     @lru_cache
     @property
     def id(self):
         company = Company.get(Company.name.upper() == self.name)
         return company.id
```

How can I make this dynamically resolved `id` property, the actual Enum int value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to get the names and ids with a function, and then use the functional API to to create the enum.  Something like:

```
CompanyEnum = Enum('CompanyEnum', get_names_ids('company'))
```

and `get_names_ids(column)` is something like:

```
def get_names_ids(column):
    # talk to dbs and get values of id and column fields
    return ... # [(id_1, company_1), (id_2, company_2), ...]
```

The `get_names_ids` may have to ensure upper-case values, etc., but that's the basics.

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.